# About Socket Classes in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

Can socket classes in Java be used to communicate with a non-Java applications? I know TCP/IP is an independent protocol suite, but I'm not sure about Java classes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You might as well make that an answer.

Comment: Yes, with the possible small-nit caveat that you aren't using the *classes* to communicate *directly* with the non-Java applications -- you are using the Socket Classes to send and receive socket messages, which can be read and written by many other languages.  But the classes are java-specific.  If the OP doesn't understand that this is possible, he may not appreciate the difference between the classes and the protocol they implement.

Comment: If this wasn't possible you wouldn't be able to read this forum. The server is Java and the client is your browser, which isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Of course they can:

> *"The java.net package in the Java platform provides a class, Socket, that implements one side of a two-way connection between your Java program **and another program** on the network."*

Emphasis added.  Note that it does NOT say "another Java program".

Reference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html

In fact, the Java `Socket` class is a thin "wrapper" for native socket APIs that are provided by the operating system.  All of the protocol implementation stuff is handled in the operating system ... on the other side of that API.  Programs written in other languages will also use the native socket APIs ... directly, or via the equivalent of Java's `Socket` class.

---

I should also correct a couple of technical mistakes in @rcook's comment:

1. Neither the java Socket class or the native socket API *implement* TCP/IP and other protocols.  The actual network protocol implementation is done *behind* the native socket API ... an possibly even in an attached processor.
2. The `Socket` class does not read and write "messages". It reads and writes bytes that may or may not be *application level* messages.  The bundling up of the bytes into network packets is handled *transparently* by the TCP/IP stack.

   (If you want a class that does network-level messaging, then `DatagramSocket` is what you after ... modulo that you can only send certain *kinds* of messages.)
3. In fact it is not *incorrect* to say that sockets / the `Socket` class are / can be used to *communicate* with other programs.  If you ignore the nitty-gritty implementation details, "communicate" is a good term for what is happening when programs use sockets.  The word "communicate" has a much broader meaning in IT than just "sending messages".